# Where can I buy "Snow White with the Red Hair" manga in English?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

I really love this anime and usually only buy manga if I really like it.     *Akagami no Shirayukihime* or *Snow White with the Red Hair*, is just an amazing story that I must have the manga of! But I can't seem to find a place to buy the English edition of the manga.

So is there an English edition out there for sale?

Answer (score 5):

Shamefully, there does not seem to be an English version of [akagami-no-shirayukihime](/questions/tagged/akagami-no-shirayukihime) right now.

But as the series is still ongoing, and already has been translated to several other languages as well. Besides the [Japanese](http://www.goodreads.com/series/59407-akagami-no-shirayukihime) version, it is not unlikely that an English translation will still follow.

The other languages that have been released (partially) are

- German: [Die rothaarige Schneeprinzessin](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11062261-die-rothaarige-schneeprinzessin-band-01)
- Indonesian: [Red Haired Snow White](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4863706-red-haired-snow-white-vol-01)
- French: [Shirayuki aux cheveux rouges](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13607521-shirayuki-aux-cheveux-rouges-tome-1)

Comment: how come indonesian version have english title?

Comment: @TanyavonDegurechaff same here.. i don know that akagami no shirayuki hime available in indonesia...